# Tensorflow cifar10.maybe_download_and_extract() gives error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I try to run a CNN model on tensorflow using cifar10 library. However, when I import cifar10 and run the `maybe_download_and_extract()` method, it gives the following error. I am running it on tensorflow (1.5.0) and Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnrecognizedFlagError                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-02a754d7036a> in <module>()
----> 1 cifar10.maybe_download_and_extract()

D:\Google Drive\Akademik\Ozyegin\CS566\Project 2\cifar10.py in maybe_download_and_extract()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\flags.py in __getattr__(self, name)
     82     # a flag.
     83     if not wrapped.is_parsed():
---> 84       wrapped(_sys.argv)
     85     return wrapped.__getattr__(name)
     86 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\absl\flags\_flagvalues.py in __call__(self, argv, known_only)
    628       suggestions = _helpers.get_flag_suggestions(name, list(self))
    629       raise _exceptions.UnrecognizedFlagError(
--> 630           name, value, suggestions=suggestions)
    631 
    632     self.mark_as_parsed()

UnrecognizedFlagError: Unknown command line flag 'f'
```

Answer (score 2):

Add following line to your jupyter notebook:

```
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('f', '', 'kernel')
```